# How to add an element to an array without any built in functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have these two questions considering the JavaScript language:

1. Is there any way to append to an array without using the push() function or any other built in functions in the language?
2. Is there any way to merge two arrays together without using the concat() function or any other built in functions in the language?

Comment: Sure, use underscore

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. Why would you want to?

Comment: "I need to make an apple pie without using apples". Good luck with that.

Comment: So let me rap that.. you're trying to to smth in javascript wihout using it?

Comment: JavaScript has an append() function?

Comment: @MarcB: http://allrecipes.com/recipe/chemical-apple-pie-no-apple-apple-pie/

Comment: I meant the concat() function not the append() sorry. But this is just a challenge I stumbled upon, why all the negative reactions?

Comment: The point of a challenge is to challenge *yourself*. It's not much of a challenge if you ask someone else for the answer.

Comment: One part of the challenge involved adding things to an array. I did try to look up the answer on google but couldn't find any appropriate answers. After seeing the solution I do feel stupid and ashamed, sorry!

Comment: The answer to both questions is *yes*. Please note that yes/no questions are not really suitable for Stack Overflow. We usually help people fix their code.

Comment: I just +1 this question because I don't see the point to -1

Answer (score 7):

For the first part you can always use the length property of the array, to add the next element:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
a[a.length] = 'e'; 

// a is now ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

To do the latter, merge the arrays, without a function you can just loop thru the arrays, should pick the largest one to loop on. But yeah, as the comments state. There's usually not a good reason to do so.

Comment: What's interesting, that this approach should work faster than `push`, single you don't call a function but work with indices directly.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the alternatives for you:

1. To add the item to the array without `push` call:

   ```
   arr[arr.length] = value;
   ```
2. To concatenate one array to another without `concat` call:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; arr1[arr1.length] = arr2[i++]);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for or why but `arr[arr.length] = 1;` is the answer both of your questions.

```
var myArr = [];
myArr[myArr.length] = 1;
myArr[myArr.length] = 2;
myArr[myArr.length] = 3;

var myArr1 = [...]; // has items;
var myArr2 = [...]; // has items;
var mergedArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < myArr1.length){
    mergedArr[mergedArr.length] = myArr1[i];
}

for(var i = 0; i < myArr2.length){
    mergedArr[mergedArr.length] = myArr2[i];
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to remove without using pop

Comment: @VikasBansal `arr.length = arr.length - 2`; should do what you want. if you also need the last item use `arr[arr.length - 1]` before that code

Comment: nice trick @onur but what if you want to delete the first element (like in queue)

Comment: @VikasBansal other than a loop I cannot think any other approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do so without using .push, concat, or .length. ES6 allows the use of the spread syntax (...):

```
var arr = [1, 2];  // arr is 1, 2
var arr = [...arr, 3];  // arr is now 1, 2, 3

let arr1 = [1, 2]; 

let arr2 = [3, 4]; 

arr = [...arr1, ...arr2];  // arr is now 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pop(arr) {
  let finalVar = arr[arr.length - 1];
  arr.length = arr.length - 1;

  return finalVar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can solve your problem:

```
const addItem = (arr, ...arguments) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    arr[arr.length] = arguments[i];
  }
  return arr;
};

let myArr = [];

console.log(addItem(myArr, 'Chaewon')); // ['Chaewon'])
console.log(addItem(myArr, 'Liz')); // ['Chaewon', 'Liz']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
    let data = [20, 80, 79, 21, 40];
    let newEl = 26;
    let position = 2;
    console.log(data);

 for(let i = data.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(data[i]);
    if (i >= position) {
        data[i + 1]= data[i];
        if (i === position) {
            data[i]= newEl;
        }

    }
 }
 console.log(data)
</script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```